# FTP socket for command is blocked after uploading a file to server via data socket

Tags: c, linux, ftp

My FTP server is IIS. I **closed the data socket** after STOR a file, however, I found the cmd socket is blocked. It's strange. It seems the server data socket is stil waiting for data.
this is my code

```
int client_data_socket = enter_passvie_mode(client_cmd_socket, client_cmd_port + 1, send_buffer, recv_buffer);
FILE *fp;
if ((fp = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL)
{
    close(client_data_socket);
    printf("open file failed\n");
    exit(1);
}
size_t char_size = sizeof(char);
char data_buffer[FILE_READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
int numread;
for (;;)
{
    bzero(data_buffer, FILE_READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
    numread = fread(data_buffer, char_size, FILE_READ_BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
    if (numread < 0)
    {
        printf("read file failed\n");
        break;
    } 
    else if (numread > 0)
    {
        int length = send(client_data_socket, data_buffer, numread, 0);
        if (length == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (length < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EINTR)
            {
                continue;
            }
            printf("[PUT] command send data failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (numread == FILE_READ_BUFFER_SIZE) continue;
    else {
        break;
    }
}
close(client_data_socket);
printf("close data socket\n");
fclose(fp);
exit(0);
```

[command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLmsG.png)
after put a file, other command is blocked, it shows socket for command is blocked. Should I do anything other to notify the server that data transmission ends?

[source code](https://github.com/salamander-mh/flyf/blob/master/ftp_client.c)

Comment: `size_t char_size = sizeof(char);` equals one. **and:** `if (numread == FILE_READ_BUFFER_SIZE) continue;
    else {
        break;` you are disallowing incomplete reads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer：
`close` will send FIN packet and destroy fd immediately when **socket is not shared with other processes**.
In my case, parent process shares `client_data_socket` with the child process. So I need to use `shutdown` function to send `FIN`.